# The Grid system in Bootstrap what am I missing?

Tags: formatting, twitter-bootstrap, html

Please feel free to correct me, but from what I understand of the bootstrap CSS is that the spans1,2,3,4 ect are supposed to make laying out data on a web page easy. One entire row is supposed to be a span12 meaning two 6 spans should equal an entire row with the contents being 50/50 spaced? Is this right so far?

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class ="span4">First name: <input  type="text"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" id="firstname"/></div>
    <div class ="span4">Last name: <input  type="text"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastname" id="lastname"/></div>
    <div class ="span2">Student Number: <input  type="text"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter Student Number" name="Student Number" id="StudentNumber"/> </div>
    <div class ="span2">Course code & Name:  <input  type="text"  runat="server" placeholder="Enter Course Code" name="CourseCode" id="CourseCode"/></div>
    <div class ="span4">Course code & Name: <input   type="text" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Course Code" name="CourseCode" id="Text1"/> </div>
</div>
```

The result looks nothing as I would expect it to. Image of the messed up form here [sample http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/6361/35787686.png](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/6361/35787686.png)

Comment: Well it would seem even though I am a new user and obviously trying my best to participate in the community through asking a question that I can assume other new users might find helpful; some one has decided to reformat the question and vote it down and not leave any constructive feed back as to why this has happened. Making me feel disinclined to participate further. Any response as to why this has happened would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Don't get angry at reformatting. It really made the post easier to read. Personally, I wouldn't vote your question down, though it could be improved. Providing a live demo, even for such a simple example is considered good practice and it makes others more likely to take a look at your problem. As for your problem. I only took a look at bootstrap after reading your question so forgive me if I'm being ignorant, but doesn't the outer `div` require a `row` class? `<div class="row hero-unit">`?

Comment: I was just bummed that I got neg feedback for bad grammar. I will not use @#$ to comment out profane words thus emphasising my frustration, this is not acceptable (apparently). Thanks Tom for your response, I  unaware you could combine classes i.e row and hero-unit.I found that people have similar trouble with bootstrap with the general response being that it's in bootstraps doco which is valid and true however their are many questions which makes me think stuffs missing. The rest of the doco is here :D http://blog.wearepropeople.com/twitter-bootstrap-the-ultimate-resources-roundup/

Comment: Did adding the class solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again Tom solution code is below:-

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <h1>Personal Details</h1></div><div class="row hero-unit">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class ="span2">First name:</div> 
    <div class="span4">
      <input  type="text"  runat="server" 
              placeholder="Enter First Name" 
              name="Firstname" id="Firstname" />
    </div>
    <div class ="span2">Last name:</div> 
    <div class="span4">
       <input  type="text"  runat="server" 
               placeholder="Enter Last Name" 
               name="Lastname" id="Lastname"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class ="span2">Student Number:</div> 
    <div class="span4"> 
      <input type="text"  runat="server" 
             placeholder="Enter Student Number" 
             name="Student Number" id="StudentNumber"/>
    </div>
    <div class ="span2">Course Name:</div> 
    <div class="span4"> 
      <input type="text"  runat="server" 
             placeholder="Enter Course Code" 
             name="CourseCode" id="CourseCode"/>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class ="span2">Mail Address:</div> 
    <div class="span10">
      <input type="text" class="span10" runat="server" 
             placeholder="Enter Postal Address" 
             name="PostalAddress" id="PostalAddress"/> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The much nicer formatting results can be seen here:- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/homepageim.png/